# Async API Request does not work in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, async-await

I created an Async Newegg API request which works fine in .NET Core Console App. however, using the same Async in ASP.NET Framework web forms is returning an "Invalid Value Exception". Clearly the request is going through, however, there is some formatting issue preventing me from reading the data normally like I would in a console app. Please advise.

```
//in this class we will authenticate our Newegg API
namespace NeweggAPI_Orders
{
    public class Newegg
    {
        private OrderCall orderCall;
        public Newegg()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("newegg config");
            APIConfig config = APIConfig.FromJsonFile(@"C:\Users\****\source\repos\NeweggAPI_Orders\NeweggAPI_Orders\JSONSettings\setting.json");            
            APIClient client = new APIClient(config);
            orderCall = new OrderCall(client);           
        }

        public async Task GetOrderStatusAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetOrderStatusAsync");
            await LoadSomeData();
        }

        public async Task LoadSomeData()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("load some data");
            try
            {
                var orderstatus = await orderCall.GetOrderStatus("105137040").ConfigureAwait(false);
                Debug.Write(orderstatus.ToStringWithNonSpace());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
}
```

and Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace NeweggAPI_Orders
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetOrderAsync));
        }

        private async Task GetOrderAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("main page: getorderasync");
            var NewEGG = new Newegg(); //initialize + config newegg client
            await NewEGG.GetOrderStatusAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
   at Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Base.BaseCall.<ProcessResponse>d__12`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Order.OrderCall.<GetOrderInformation>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NeweggAPI_Orders.Newegg.<LoadInfo>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Vinotronics_2021\source\repos\NeweggAPI_Orders\NeweggAPI_Orders\Newegg.cs:line 100
```

Comment: Where in the code does the error occur? Is it a .NET error that's happening, or an error thrown by the API you're calling?

Comment: @AnnL. The API throws an error itself . When I do the same async task in ConsoleApp it works fine, but here it can't.

Comment: Have tried using Fiddler to look at the HTTP request and response? What's the type of the exception? Does a synchronous reques succeed?